# MySQL: Typecasting NULL to 0

Tags: sql, mysql, casting

Let us suppose the following table (e.g. a result of several inner join statements):

```
id | column_1 | column_2
------------------------
 1 |  1       | 
 2 |  2       | 2
 3 |          | 3
```

Which you could for example get from the following statement:

```
select a.id, t1.column_1, t2.column_2
from a
left join t1 on a.id = t1.id
left join t2 on a.id = t2.id
```

Now, if i'd like to sum up t1.column_1 and t2.column_2 as follows

```
select 
    a.id, 
    t1.column_1, 
    t2.column_2,
    (t1.column_1 + t2.column_2) as cumulated
from a
left join t1 on a.id = t1.id
left join t2 on a.id = t2.id
```

The result will look as follows:

```
id | column_1 | column_2 | cumulated
------------------------------------
 1 |  1       | NULL     | NULL
 2 |  2       | 2        | 4
 3 |  NULL    | 3        | NULL
```

My question basically is: is there a way to typecast NULL into 0 in order to do some math?

I have tried `CONVERT(t1.column_1, SIGNED)` and `CAST(t1.column_1 as SIGNED)`, but a `NULL` stays a `NULL`.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Use `IFNULL(column, 0)` to convert the column value to zero.

Alternatively, the COALESCE function will do the same thing: `COALESCE(column, 0)`, except

1. `COALESCE` is ANSI-compliant, `IFNULL` is not
2. `COALESCE` takes an arbitrary number of columns/values and will return the first non-null value passed to it.

Comment: and coalesce can have more than one value ?

Comment: Yes...so COALESCE(column1, column2, 0) will return the first non-null of these values.  Bear in mind this works horizontally, not vertically.  The columns must belong to the same table row.

Comment: @rexem: Thanks, that's very nice of you to say.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @David Andres A million thank-yous. If only I could upvote a second time.