# Adding columns in MySQL - how to treat NULL as 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I have simple table (test) where I need to perform some additions (I want to get a row total and a column total).

```
 id  var1  var2
 1   NULL  NULL
 2   10    NULL
```

For column totals, summing works as expected (NULL is ignored in the addition):

```
SELECT SUM(var1) FROM test

10
```

For row totals, addition does not ignore NULL (if any column is NULL the result is NULL):

```
SELECT var1+var2 FROM test

NULL
NULL
```

What I want it to return is:

```
SELECT var1+var2 FROM test

NULL
10
```

Is there a way to get MySQL to treat NULL as 0 in an addition?

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441333/mysql-typecasting-null-to-0

Comment: Consider normalizing your data. Adding columns is an unusual requirement.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use the `IFNULL` function

```
SELECT IFNULL(var1, 0) + IFNULL(var2, 0) FROM test
```

Answer (score 26):

You want to use `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(var1, 0) + coalesce(var2, 0)
```

`coalesce()` is ANSI standard and available in most databases (including MySQL).

Comment: This is more portable than the other solutions

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
Case when (coalesce(`var1`, 0) + coalesce(`var2`, 0))=0
then NULL
else coalesce(`var1`, 0) + coalesce(`var2`, 0)
end
from test
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62cbf/6)**