# Null value to zero mysql

Tags: null, sum, addition

Dears I am trying to add some values from diffrent tables but some values are empty at some point so due to empty its result become empty .

So plz give me any tips of MYSQL that convert empty to zero (0).

e.g : 1+2+empty(Null)+3 = empty

Help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Typecasting NULL to 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441333/mysql-typecasting-null-to-0)

Answer (score 0):

Let x be the expression (e.g a field), which should be substituted with zero when it is null.
Then you can use

```
IF(x IS NULL,0,x)
```

in place of x. The IF function gives its second argument if the first argument (the condition) is true, and the third argument if its first argument is false.

Regards