# how to use if else subquery in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT IF{ 
    (select sum(amount) 
     from bank_credit 
     where bank_name='IDBI') - 
    (select sum(amount) 
     from bank_debit 
     where bank_name='IDBI') as idbi == NULL} 
 else {
     select sum(amount) 
     from bank_credit 
     where bank_name='IDBI')
} as idbi
```

how to solve this sub query with if else in mysql... plz help some one

Comment: Can you explain in regular language what your query is supposed to do?

Comment: And also what is happening when you run it. Are there any errors? There should be as this is not valid ANSI SQL or MySQL.

Comment: Check [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

Comment: using Sub query sum of two colum subraction , if second colum their has no any value , then = answer gives null

Comment: SELECT (select sum(amount) from bank_credit where bank_name='IDBI') - (select sum(amount) from bank_debit where bank_name='IDBI') as idbi

Comment: i getting null value if... second colum has no value..

Comment: @ShoaibAli, that's because anything + null = null.  So you need to replace the nulls with 0s - `coalesce(amount,0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [function `ifnull()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) to convert the `NULL` to a `0` and just calculate with that.

```
SELECT 
  IFNULL(
    ( SELECT SUM(amount) 
        FROM bank_credit 
        WHERE bank_name='IDBI'
    ), 0
  )
  - 
  IFNULL(
    (
      SELECT SUM(amount) 
        FROM bank_debit 
        WHERE bank_name='IDBI' 
    ), 0
  ) AS idbi;
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/1441358/1331451.

---

Take a look at the behaviour of the `isnull()` with this query:

```
select 
  ifnull( (select 1), 0)    - ifnull( (select 1), 0)    as 1_1,
  ifnull( (select 1), 0)    - ifnull( (select 0), 0)    as 1_0,
  ifnull( (select 1), 0)    - ifnull( (select NULL), 0) as 1_NULL,
  ifnull( (select 0), 0)    - ifnull( (select 1), 0)    as 0_1,
  ifnull( (select NULL), 0) - ifnull( (select 1), 0)    as NULL_1,
  ifnull( (select NULL), 0) - ifnull( (select NULL), 0) as NULL_NULL
;
```

Comment: Thnx but... if their is no any value in colum then also giving null value....  ifnull and COALESCE is also not working

Comment: if their have value but null in the colum then ifnull and COALESCE is working fine..... but colum is empty .... ifnull and COALESCE not working

Comment: Just use the `IFNULL` with both subqueries and it will return a `0` if one or both of the subquery results are `NULL`.

Comment: if one sub query gives null value then other also.. gives null value

Comment: @ShoaibAli please define your desired output instead of rambling about in half-sentences. I don't know what you want.

Comment: i was trying to say..... their has... two table : table1 and table2 both as column name (AMOUNT) are same , sum of AMOUNT with table1 has a value 500 in colum,  and sum of AMOUNT with table2 has no value  colum and table2 are empty, when subraction of sum of amount from both table, gives value null, for example: Select sum(amount) from table1 - sum(amount) from table2     .Gives Null value