# How to SELECT Non Exist Row in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

[image]

And here is the data:

### Products

[image]

### Orders

[image]

I want to have a query that produces this result:

[image]

I have tried this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, sum(o.amount) AS total
    FROM products AS p 
    INNER JOIN orders AS o ON o.product_id = p.id 
    GROUP BY p.id
```

But I get this:

[image]

How can I get the result as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have to do a left outer join like that:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, IFNULL(sum(o.amount), 0) AS total
    FROM products AS p 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN orders AS o ON o.product_id = p.id 
    GROUP BY p.id
```

the [OUTER]-Keyword is optional and can be left out.

Have a look at this question: [MySQL: Typecasting NULL to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441333/mysql-typecasting-null-to-0)

But sorry, this really is so basic, you can google it all around the world in every language...

Comment: Thanks bro. Working great!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Left Join](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-left-join.aspx)
The MySQL LEFT JOIN clause allows you to query data from two or more database tables. The LEFT JOIN clause is an optional part of the SELECT statement, which appears after the FROM clause.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id,p.name,(SELECT SUM(o.amount) FROM orders o WHERE o.product_id=p.id) total
FROM products p
```