# Return a value of 0 or 0.00 along with where clause MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, join, case

While I was debugging and seeing some test with my query, I noticed that some of my results have **NULL** values. I want to return them or see them as a value of 0 or 0.00 according to their type just like the Senior.

I tried it with a case statement but it didn't get the result I wanted which is 0.

This is determined through where clause according to type.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT a.ID as EMPLOYEE, a.DOB as Date, a.AMOUNT as DECLARED, 
(SELECT (CASE WHEN 

SUM(gndsale.AMOUNT) and gndsale.ID IS NULL then "0" and gndsale.typeid = "10" else 
SUM(gndsale.AMOUNT) END) 
from gndsale where gndsale.ID= b.ID and 
gndsale.typeid = "10" and gndsale.DOB = a.DOB)  as `SENIOR DISCOUNT` 

FROM 
gndsale a INNER JOIN emp b ON a.ID= b.ID WHERE a.type = "22" and STR_TO_DATE(a.DOB, 
'%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-31' GROUP BY DECLARED order by STR_TO_DATE(a.DOB, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Here is my result:

[image]

I want to make that Null Value as 0

Comment: See the [`IFNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function.

Comment: Does this post help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441333/mysql-typecasting-null-to-0

Comment: This is a faq, please next time google a clear concise statement of your question. After you have browsed/googled site:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace null with 0 in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532776/replace-null-with-0-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to wrap your subquery with `COALESCE()` and use zero as a default value:

```
SELECT
    a.ID AS EMPLOYEE,
    a.DOB AS Date,
    a.AMOUNT AS DECLARED, 
    COALESCE(
        (SELECT
            CASE WHEN SUM(gndsale.AMOUNT) AND gndsale.ID IS NULL AND gndsale.typeid = "10"
                 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(gndsale.AMOUNT) END
        FROM gndsale
        WHERE gndsale.ID = b.ID AND
              gndsale.typeid = "10" AND
              gndsale.DOB = a.DOB), 0) AS `SENIOR DISCOUNT` 
FROM gndsale a
INNER JOIN emp b
    ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE a.type = "22" AND
      STR_TO_DATE(a.DOB, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-31' 
GROUP BY DECLARED
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(a.DOB, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: THIS GOT THE RESULT I WANTED!! Can I ask, what is difference if you added coalesce even though you have an IS NULL function?

Comment: @VirgilCruz First, I think this query is messy, and we can probably get rid of that ugly subquery and replace it with conditional aggregation.  To answer your question: There is no real difference between `ISNULL` and `COALESCE`; they are synonyms of each other.  You can use whichever one you want.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'll fix my messy query once I got all the results I wanted in one Select statement statement

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select EMPLOYEE,`Date`,DECLARED,case when SENIOR_DISCOUNT is null then 0 else SENIOR_DISCOUNT end as `SENIOR DISCOUNT` from
(SELECT a.ID as EMPLOYEE, a.DOB as Date, a.AMOUNT as DECLARED, 
(SELECT (CASE WHEN 

SUM(gndsale.AMOUNT) and gndsale.ID IS NULL then "0" and gndsale.typeid = "10" else 
SUM(gndsale.AMOUNT) END) 
from gndsale where gndsale.ID= b.ID and 
gndsale.typeid = "10" and gndsale.DOB = a.DOB)  as `SENIOR_DISCOUNT` 

FROM 
gndsale a INNER JOIN emp b ON a.ID= b.ID WHERE a.type = "22" and STR_TO_DATE(a.DOB, 
'%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-31' GROUP BY DECLARED order by STR_TO_DATE(a.DOB, '%m/%d/%Y')) as a
```